# Left Join for 2 lists of objects in Java

Tags: java, lambda, left-join

I have 2 lists of object in Java

```
List<Object1> list1
List<Object2> list2

Object1 has fields:
- fieldA
- fieldB
- fieldC
- fieldsD

Object2 has fields:
- fieldB
- fieldE
- fieldF
```

So, both Object1 and Object2 has same field “fieldB”.

What I wanted to do is to implement some kind of “LEFT JOIN” , that will join all objects from **list1** and **list2**  and creates another  **List list3**, where **Object3** has all fields from both **Object1** and **Object2**

I have large amount of data, so the approach should be really fast.
And recommendations on how to implement it in Java?

Comment: is using an in-memory database an option?

Comment: What is join-condition? "SELECT * FROM Object1 LEFT JOIN Object2 ON ?"

Comment: @hsl no,it's not an option for me(

Comment: @saka1029  , my new Object3 should have all l fields from Object1 and all fileds from Object2. And join Object1 and Object2 on "fieldB"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Java stream's parallel operation in order to speed things up:

```
    List<Object3> list3 = list1.stream().parallel()
    .map( o1 -> merge( new Object3(), o1 ) )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() );

    Map<Object, Object3> map = list3.stream().parallel()
    .collect( Collectors.toConcurrentMap( Object3::getFieldB, Function.identity() ) );

    list2.stream().parallel().forEach( o2 -> {
        Object3 o3 = map.get( o2.getFieldB() );
        if (o3 != null) merge(o3, o2);
    } );

    Object3 merge(Object3 o3, Object1 o1){...}
    Object3 merge(Object3 o3, Object2 o2){...}
```

`list3` will contain your result.

Comment: Building the Map first and then do a merge run should avoid one iteration through list1.

Comment: Just using the `map` to get `list3` might not work because of possibility that we might have multiple `Object3` with same value for `fieldB`. One possibility to avoid iterating twice over first list is to create custom collector that will collect both to `map` and the `list3` at the same time during one stream operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one iteration per list by creating a `Map` in one run:

```
Map<FieldBType, List<Object1>> map = list1.parallelStream()
                         .groupingBy(Object1::getFieldB);
```

which will create a map with the values of FieldB as keys and all objects from list1 with the corresponding fieldB value as values.

Now you can stream the other list and merge with the appropriate `Object1`s from the corresponding lists.

```
List<Object3> = list2.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(o2 -> merge(o2, map.getOrDefault(o2.getFieldB(), Collections.emptyList())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with a helper method

```
// creates a stream of Object3 from the Object1s from the list
// merged with the values of the given Object2
Stream<Object3> merge(Object2 o2, List<Object1> o1s) {
    return o2s.parallelStream().map(o2 -> merge(o1, o2));
}

Object3 merge(Object o1, Object o2) { ... }
```